# How can I put a "broken" Crystal Report reference back together?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I've got a project I've moved over from VS2008 to VS2010.

The VS2008 project contains some Crystal Reports files.

Yesterday, someone asked me to add a new element to one of these. I did so. Crystal Reports now won't load the file.

I realise there's some difference between Crystal Reports in VS2008 and VS2010, so I tried to roll the files back to the copies in version control (SourceSafe! Boo, hiss!) and they've been re-imported into Visual Studio incorrectly.

What was previously a myReport.rpt reference, with an invisible myReport.vb backing is now a reference to a myReport.vb file, and a reference to a myReport.rpt file, which has generated a *different* myReport1.vb file to be its backing.

Now, I can just go through and fix this problem manually by copying the code across, obviously, but I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to get these files out from version control without this happening every single time.

EDIT: I would guess that this question would also apply to repairing the split between disassociated .frm/.vb files and .xaml/.vb files.

Comment: What do you mean "Crystal Reports now won't load the file."? What error message do you get?